# Convert Persian to English numbers issue

Tags: php

I am converting Persian to English/Digit numbers but I have the problem with two different arrays. Having same function but the output is different.

```
function convertNumbers($number)
{
   $arr2 = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹']; // Converting

   $arr1 = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩']; // Not converting

   $num = range(0, 9);

   $englishNumber[0] = str_replace($arr1, $num, $number);

   $englishNumber[1] = str_replace($arr2, $num, $number);

   return $englishNumber;
}

print_r(convertNumbers('۹۰'));
```

> OUTPUT: Array ( [0] => ۹۰ [1] => 90 )

The `$arr2` is working fine but `$arr1` is not. Look like the 4 and the 6 is different in these above two declared arrays as well as arrangement like left to right and vice versa.  Any advice guys.

Comment: For me it looks like `$arr1` is `array_reverse($arr2)`. Also you never use these arrays. Can you clarify issue?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: @04FS sir if you use `$arr1` in the function, it will not work and not convert to English/digit number. On the other hand `$arr2` is working fine. This is what I asking. Because there are small differences in both arrays. but the output is not the same. That's what I need to understand and try to getting answer.

Comment: @HassanRaza The returning output should be different, since it's 2 different arrays - not even the reverse of each other. What is the result you are getting, and what do you expect? (Others: arr1 and 2 are examples, they are subsituted in place of $persian.) (Maybe you should try range('0', '9')?)

Comment: @kry question updated and output added.

Comment: Something is weird here, `var_dump($arr1[0], $arr1[9]);` results in `string '٠' (length=2)`, `string '٩' (length=2)` - should be the other way around?

Comment: @04FS Why it should be the other way around?

Comment: You are putting in the wrong input! You are checking both arabic and persian numbers, but input only persian - it's not converting, because they look similar, but two completly different numbers, so there is nothing to convert. See: print_r(convertNumbers('۹۰')); AND print_r(convertNumbers('٩٠'));

Comment: @revo because the code creating $arr1 has `٩` in the first position, and `٠` in the last …? There seems to be some LTR/RTL stuff going on here as well with these characters.

Comment: @04FS That different direction is because of that HTML code block rendering otherwise `$arr1[0]` and `$arr2[0]` contain the similar character `0`.

Comment: @revo ah okay that makes sense, thanks :-)

Comment: It's merely an encoding issue, the elements of arrays look the same, but different in bits - like strict comparing 1 === '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$arr2` seems to contain Persian digits and `$arr1` seems to contain Arabic digits. It means `٠` in the first array isn't the same `۰` in the second array, although shapes are similar.

To ensure they are different you could run `bin2hex()`:

```
foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
   echo $key, ': ', bin2hex($value), ' - ', bin2hex($arr1[$key]), "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
0: dbb0 - d9a0
1: dbb1 - d9a1
2: dbb2 - d9a2
3: dbb3 - d9a3
4: dbb4 - d9a4
5: dbb5 - d9a5
6: dbb6 - d9a6
7: dbb7 - d9a7
8: dbb8 - d9a8
9: dbb9 - d9a9
```

Answer (score 1):

The arrays $ arr1 and $ arr2 contain different characters. After convert to unicode it is visible.

```
$arr1 = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩']; 
$arr2 = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
```

$arr1 contain the characters ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO .. ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT NINE

```
\u{660}\u{661}\u{662}\u{663}\u{664}\u{665}\u{666}\u{667}\u{668}\u{669}
```

and $arr2 EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO .. EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT NINE

```
\u{6f0}\u{6f1}\u{6f2}\u{6f3}\u{6f4}\u{6f5}\u{6f6}\u{6f7}\u{6f8}\u{6f9}
```

I think which array is used depends on the writing direction. But I'm **not** a language expert.

**Note added**:

This Unicode sequence enclosed in double quotes may use in PHP sources and the output is the UTF-8 representation of this code point.

```
  $persNum = [ //"۰" .. "۹"
    "\u{6f0}","\u{6f1}","\u{6f2}","\u{6f3}","\u{6f4}",
    "\u{6f5}","\u{6f6}","\u{6f7}","\u{6f8}","\u{6f9}"
  ];
```

Characters with the same shapes can now not be confused.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using 2 different codings. It's like you have an array from A to C, and an other from D to F, and change every A-C to a number - won't change anything the second array. In your example:

```
function convertNumbers($number)
{
   $arr2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']; // Converting

   $arr1 = ['F', 'E', 'D']; // Not converting

   $num = range(0, 2);

   $englishNumber[0] = str_replace($arr1, $num, $number);

   $englishNumber[1] = str_replace($arr2, $num, $number);

   return $englishNumber;
}

print_r(convertNumbers('AC'));
```

will always change AC, but never DF.

```
array(0 => "02", 1 => "DF")
```

Long story short, the letters of the input parameters are logically different, even if they look same, and str_replace does not find the same string in array1. One of them is in Persian, and the other is Arabic, but you only check your output for one of them.

(Funfact: They are called Arabic Numbers, not English Numbers. :P )

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertPersianNumbersToEnglish($input) {
$persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '٤', '۵', '٥', '٦', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
$english = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9];
return str_replace($persian, $english, $input);
}
echo convertPersianNumbersToEnglish("۲");
```

Comment: this will print 2